# After deleting all users, how do I reset the user ID to start from 2?

Tags: users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [After deleting all nodes, how do I reset the node ID to start from 1 again?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/after-deleting-all-nodes-how-do-i-reset-the-node-id-to-start-from-1-again)

This is a very similar question with [After deleting all nodes, how do I reset the node ID to start from 1 again?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/after-deleting-all-nodes-how-do-i-reset-the-node-id-to-start-from-1-again) but was wondering how this can be done for User table in Drupal 7?

Comment: 'ALTER TABLE `node` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;' is still the correct answer. Just replace `node` with `users`

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to integrate that in the code, let's say reset the UID to the last available one when a user has been deleted? Since this is manual coding it would be hard to do that.

Comment: Thank you tostinni, as I mentioned in my question (and I have referred to the similar post) I am asking for similar solution but for users table, but thanks for the negative vote anyway

Comment: I disagree that this is a dup and downvote worthy.  One, the answer isn't the same b/c the table name is different.  Two, @Luca did show effort b/c he pointed out the similar question.

Comment: The tables are different, and the initial values are different; still, when somebody knows how to do that with a table, knows also how to do it with every table. In both the cases, the warning is "don't do that."