# How to reset UID number back to default order?

Tags: 7, users, database

I have a Drupal 7 website with only UID1 user which is root admin. I deleted previous users. Now if I create a new user, it gets UID of e.g. 74.

It should be UID 2 and so on.

Anyway, I had same problem with resetting nodes back to 1. And I did it by following [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/after-deleting-all-nodes-how-do-i-reset-the-node-id-to-start-from-1-again), but it worked only if you have no nodes. Now, I have at least one user and I don't know if that query would work for 'users'.

Comment: It works for any database table. BTW, Drupal considers user with UID 1 is always the root admin. No matter if you have recreated it.

Comment: So I ran the ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; but didn't work.

Comment: Ah...you are right. Sorry for giving wrong information. I've found the possible reason [here](https://api.drupal.org/comment/58438#comment-58438).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the [discussion thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/356074) about the issue about why `users` table is not auto-increment and creating a new `sequences` table for that purpose.

> This is NOT a full sequences API not at all but it's enough for some uses. actions_aid and simpletest_test_id , that's duplicate code not to mention it belongs to the DB layer. This patch solves that. Further work: we can reuse this for users.uid as that should not be serial because of the known problems. The postgresql folks can create a version which uses proper sequences. The mysql folks can support more than the single serial mysql allows -- like a timestamp and a serial. Sorry for the hasty writeup.

In your case, you just update the value in `sequences` table to `1`.

**AND**

You need to run `ALTER TABLE sequences AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` as well.

Comment: I did that. But it resets back to 83 when creating new user.

Comment: You need to alter `sequences` table to start from 1. Please check the updated answer.